# Office365 Alert Policy for emails with matching header

Tags: alerts, office365

Is it possible to configure an alert policy in Office365 that would trigger if an email was received that contained a specific header and value pair?

I cannot find anything that indicates this is possible, even using Powershell Net-ProtectionAlert cmdlet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define alert policy for M365 Connector Activity](https://serverfault.com/questions/1057854/define-alert-policy-for-m365-connector-activity)

Comment: No that was my initial attempt at getting some help but this is more targeted